# HTML access a file in a completley different directory tree

Tags: html, filepath

I am trying to display an image on my html site with this piece of code. BTW everything is handled locally. There are no servers involved.

```
"<a href='http://www.stonybrook.edu/'><img class='sbu_navbar' alt='Stony Brook University' src=" + 'Users/Natan/NetBeansProjects/Homework Four/TAManager_Solution/images/yale.png' + "></a>";
```

The important part is this part

```
src=" + 'Users/Natan/NetBeansProjects/Homework Four/TAManager_Solution/images/yale.png' + "></a>";
```

I know that the format is weird but I need it that way because I will be replacing the actual path with data from a json file so it won't be hardcoded.

This directory is a completely different directory from where all my html files are based and it seems like the directory starts at the root of my computer. Is there any way to access this file?

Basically I want to set it up so I can point to any image on my hard drive, get its file path, and show it.

Comment: No servers are involved now, but can you use one locally if you want to?

Answer (score 0):

ok. put this

> `./` same directory
>
> `/` root directory
>
> `../` back one folder
>
> `../../` back two folders

then...

```
<img src="../img/marvel.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is at all related to my question. I'm talking about files that could be anywhere in the hard drive. Not just going back one folder. And I have tried all of this.

Comment: `/` this is root directory. e.g. html file on desktop and IMG in `C` folder: apply `<img src="/marvel.jpg"></img>`

Comment: Im talking more about how I already have the exact specific file path I need and I want access it. And like I said i tried all of those and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you supply the correct protocol and fully qualified path.

Try something like `<img src="file://C/full/path/to/img.jpg" />`

Note: this will only work locally. If deployed to a server, it will not work

Comment: This seems to cause a problem because one of my folders (Homework Four) has a space in it.

Comment: You need to URL encode the space (and any other special characters). E.g: `file://C/Homework%20Four/full/path/to/img.jpg`